# Include single and double quotes in ValidateExpression

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I am using the following regularfieldexpression. How to include double quotes in it.

```
ValidationExpression="^((?:[A-Za-z0-9- \+=\;\^.,@:?()$#/\\\+|[#])*&?)$"
```

I should allow all the special characters other than <>!&.

Comment: Can you please give us acceptable and non valid string which you want to test by validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
ValidationExpression = "^((?:[^<>!&]*)&?)$"
```

Because of the `^` in the beginning of `[^<>!&]` it means "match any character that isn't any of the following: `<>!&`".

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e((%3f%3a%5b%5e%3c%3e!%26%5d*)%26%3f)%24&i=hello%26&o=m)

Comment: all characters other than <>&!.  +; is allowed only if i am using it like \+\;4

Comment: @Nathiya The second expression?

Comment: i have removed @. now its working fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Nathiya Weird it doesn't work with the `@`, glad it works now

Comment: we are using telerik controls may be problem with that.